# support of Dockerization in new version of SAP Hybris

Tags: docker, jenkins, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to build a job in Jenkins which will responsible for launching SAP Hybris in docker environment,

for the 1808.5 version, I can find a recipe for docker as **b2c_acc_dockerized** where i can generate dockerfiles to build images of SAP Hybris, but for new version like 1905 and new version there is no recipe for docker,

did they not support docker recipe anymore ? Please help

what do you propose for me to do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker is still supported after 1811. It's all described on the [SAP Help](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2011/en-US/a5cb538ba19f4502865c53953f6f5e3e.html)

You can either create your own recipe. Or make use of the ant command `createPlatformImageStructure`

### Recipe

```
apply plugin: 'installer-platform-plugin'
apply plugin: 'installer-platform-containerization-plugin'
 
def pl = platform {
    extensions {
        extensionNames 'backoffice'
    }
     
    localProperties {
        property 'persistence.legacy.mode', 'false'
    }
}
 
def dpl = deployment('mySampleDeployment') {
    hsqlImage 'myHsql'
 
    solrImage 'mySolr'
     
    platformImage('myPlatform') {
        basedOn pl
         
        aspect('onlyBackoffice') {
            enabledWebApps 'backoffice'
        }
         
        aspect('onlyHac') {
            enabledWebApps 'hac'
             
            localProperties {
                property 'persistence.legacy.mode', 'true'
            }
        }
         
        aspect('allWebApps') {
            enableAllWebApps()
        }
         
        aspect('noneWebApps')
    }
}   
         
task createImagesStructure {
    doLast {
        dpl.createImagesStructure()
    }
}
```

### Ant command

Alternativly, you can look into the ant command `createPlatformImageStructure`

Before you run this command, you need to run

```
ant clean all
```

and

```
ant production -Dproduction.include.tomcat=false -Dproduction.legacy.mode=false -Dtomcat.legacy.deployment=false -Dproduction.create.zip=false
```

Finally you can run

```
ant createPlatformImageStructure
```

### Resources

For more detailed info, you can have a look in the [SAP Help](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2011/en-US/a5cb538ba19f4502865c53953f6f5e3e.html)

Comment: thanks for your response, i'm trying to move the b2c_acc_dockeriezed folder from the version 1808 and put it in the new version, I'm not sure if this will work, or if there is a good way to do it, please have you do this before: trying to generate dockerfiles from ant tasks

Comment: hi i tried using ant task it works thanks, but i can't find the secrets folder (ssl ..)

Comment: for the secret folder, you need to mount that in docker. have a look at the wiki of SAP (https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2011/en-US/fff2e115e08b494184797e81b1a71c31.html) 

In the startup command you can see a volume for the secrets folder with ssl certificates for your environment. `docker run -it --rm -v /Desktop/dockerPOC/secrets\:/etc/ssl/certs/hybris -v /Desktop/dockerPOC/tmp_medias\:/opt/hybris/data/media -p '8099:8088' --env-file env_vars platform`